# How to manage uris like <http://www.wikidata.org/.well-known/genid/d50f382e536becbbbc0987cd91bf1287> in wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

When I run the following query on WDQS

```
select distinct ?creator
where
{
  ?s wdt:P31 wd:Q3305213;  wdt:P170 ?creator .
}
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100000
```

I get a lot of uris like
http://www.wikidata.org/.well-known/genid/d50f382e536becbbbc0987cd91bf1287

And I'm unable to get useful data from these URIs. For example with

```
select ?p ?o
where
{
  <http://www.wikidata.org/.well-known/genid/d50f382e536becbbbc0987cd91bf1287> ?p ?o
}
```

How to interpret these uris? I expect to get properties of creators and I get nothing.
I've seen the following page with seems related to my question:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/Blank_Node_Skolemization

Thank in advance for any help

Comment: These skolemized URIs in RDF dump and WDQS correspond to "some values", or "unknown values" in Wikibase. Use `wikibase:isSomeValue` to filter them in SPARQL. In Wikibase, these "unknown values" do not have further properties, in RDF too. Before https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T244341, these "some values" were serialized in RDF as blank nodes. Now they are URIs, but still considered different from each other.
https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel#PropertySomeValueSnak

Comment: OK. It's a good clarification for me. A complementary question could be: how to create such item with Wikidataintegrator? Typically, I have artworks from anonymous creator, but I know that the creator was living in a specific country (ex: Italy) and in a specific period (ex: century 17th) (remark: is it necessary to create a separate question?)

Comment: AFAIK, no way. In Wikibase data model, unknown values cannot have subsequent properties.